# Access a build system from another build system in Sublime Text 2

Tags: r, sublimetext2, knitr

I'm attempting to create a build system for knitr/Sweave in Sublime Text 2. My current, simple (and working) build system is as follows:

```
{
    "cmd": ["bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/R64 CMD Sweave '${file_name}' && pdflatex '${file_base_name}.tex' -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 %S -f -pdf && /Applications/Skim.app/Contents/MacOS/Skim '${file_base_name}.pdf'"], 
    "path": "$PATH:/usr/texbin:/usr/local/bin", 
    "selector": "text.tex.latex.sweave","shell":false,
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]+): ([0-9]*)([^\\.]+)"
}
```

*(The `text.text.latex.sweave` context is defined in the Sweave Textmate bundle, which kind of works in Sublime Text)*

The build system takes a `.Rnw` file, converts it to TeX, and then runs `pdflatex` on it. This build system works, but it is fairly limited in how it opens Skim (it just opens the PDF—that's all). The LaTeXTools Sublime Text package is far more robust and opens/refreshes Skim while highlighting modified lines and providing Skim's magic reverse search.

I don't want to rewrite the LaTeXTools build system, especially since it does most of the heavy lifting (and Skim magic) with a separate Python script. However, I would really like to be able to use it to build a TeX file generated from Sweave.

Ideally, I'd love to somehow nest a build system—convert an `.Rnw` file to TeX and then immediately run the LaTeXTools build system that already exists. In pseudocode:

```
{
    [CONVERT RNW TO ${file_name}.tex && RUN THE LATEXTOOLS BUILD SYSTEM ON ${file_name}.tex]
}
```

Is it possible to access a build system from inside another build system (or alternatively, access a build system from bash)?

Comment: at least the reverse search part might be difficult, and that is where RStudio has put a fair amount of efforts to make it work; for the `knitr` part, perhaps this works: `"cmd": ["Rscript", "-e", "knitr::knit('${file_name}')"]` and the rest of the work is your question: how to call LaTeXTools? I do not use Sublime Text, so I do not know...

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to move away from RStudio (as much as I love it), since Sublime Text is a superior editor. I've got a language definition and build system for knitr as well, but it has the same problem—how can I build the compiled TeX file (either made from Sweave or knitr) using LaTeXTools' more robust build system?

Comment: I'd [love](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/449) to know a solution as well :)

Comment: Here are all my ST files: https://github.com/andrewheiss/KnitrSublime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a patch to two files in the LatexTools plugin in order to deal with Rnw files, and one patch to the Latex plugin in order to make Rnw files to behave like LaTeX files.

First the patch to the Latex plugin, in specific to the file LaTeX.tmLanguage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>fileTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>tex</string>
        <string>Rnw</string>
    </array>
```

Observe how I added an element to the array in order to deal with Rnw extensions.

Now the patch to makePDF.py

look for a a line like this

```
if self.tex_ext.upper() != ".TEX":
    sublime.error_message("%s is not a TeX source file: cannot compile." % (os.path.basename(view.file_name()),))
    return
```

and replace it with

```
if (self.tex_ext.upper() != ".TEX") and (self.tex_ext.upper() != ".RNW"):
    sublime.error_message("%s is not a TeX or Rnw source file: cannot compile." % (os.path.basename(view.file_name()),))
    return
```

Then look for a line like

```
os.chdir(tex_dir)
CmdThread(self).start()
print threading.active_count()
```

and replace it with

```
os.chdir(tex_dir)
if self.tex_ext.upper() == ".RNW":
    # Run Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('" + self.file_name + "')"
    os.system("Rscript -e \"library(knitr); knit('"+ self.file_name +"')\"")
    self.file_name = self.tex_base + ".tex"
    self.tex_ext = ".tex"
CmdThread(self).start()
print threading.active_count()
```

The last patch is to the file jumpToPDF.py

look for a line

```
if texExt.upper() != ".TEX":
    sublime.error_message("%s is not a TeX source file: cannot jump." % (os.path.basename(view.fileName()),))
    return
```

and replace it with

```
if (texExt.upper() != ".TEX") and (texExt.upper() != ".RNW"):
    sublime.error_message("%s is not a TeX or Rnw source file: cannot jump." % (os.path.basename(view.fileName()),))
    return
```

Good luck!

Comment: Holy crap! This is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind if I clean this up a bit (i.e. combine with my knitr language definition, etc.) and submit it as a pull request to the LaTeX Tools repository?

Comment: Not at all, I have another addition in order to have syntax highlighted and recognized.

Comment: Yeah, me too. I haven't gotten around to sending the pull request to LaTeX Tools since it seems like a really niche need, but I included it in my package at https://github.com/andrewheiss/KnitrSublime

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the detailed description of the required changes Herberto!

I just went ahead and changed the mentioned files. Everything works like a charm!
One thing is though, not sure if it is required, but I recompiled both python files to .pyc after editing them.

```
python -m py_compile makePDF.py
```

does the job. Should anyone run into an "invalid syntax error" at the line

```
print threading.active_count()
```

while recompiling, just replace it with:

```
print(threading.active_count())
```

Also, since the log parser of LaTeXTools only displays errors from the log files, we might be interested to see the knitr output as well. You can store it in a separate log file by replacing:

```
os.system("Rscript -e \"library(knitr); knit('"+ self.file_name +"')\"")
```

with:

```
    knitcmd = "/usr/bin/Rscript -e \"library(knitr); knit('"+ self.file_name +"')\""
    process = subprocess.Popen(knitcmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    #Launch the shell command:
    knit_output, knit_error = process.communicate()
    #store results in a log
    knit_log = open(self.tex_base + "_knitrbuild.log", "w")
    knit_log.write(knit_output)
    knit_log.write(knit_error)
    knit_log.close()
```

Before I was using a simple bash script to build the documents (Mac specific):

```
#!/bin/bash
[ $# -eq 0 ] && { echo "Usage: $0 file.Rnw for knitting"; exit 1; }
rnw="library(knitr);knit("\'"$1.Rnw"\'")"
echo "Rscript executing:" $rnw
tex="$1.tex"
pdf="$1.pdf"
Rscript -e $rnw && pdflatex $tex && pdflatex $tex && open -a Preview $pdf

retval=$?
[ $retval -eq 0 ] && echo "$rnw knitted and $pdf ready"
```

but being able to customize LaTeXTools and run it directly from ST2 with Skim support is very nice.

Is there any reasons why you wouldn't want to add the changes you outlined directly into your package source? (maybe my it's only my version that's too old.)

Comment: I can't put the changes directly into the ST package because they all deal with the LaTeXTools package, which I have no control over. In the [actual ST package](https://github.com/andrewheiss/SublimeKnitr) I explain the process of manually patching (for both ST 2 and 3, now). Additionally, you can use a new package called [latexing](http://www.latexing.com/) that has built-in support for knitr and Skim.

Comment: Oh, and ST should compile the files to `.pyc` automatically.